# Creating constraints dynamically in pyomo abstract model

Tags: optimization, pyomo, constraint-programming, graphs, logical-constraints

I have a networkX graph with few nodes and these nodes have attributes such as "demand".

```
def mygraph():
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from([("N1", {"demand": 10}),
    ("N2"{"demand": 12}),
    ("N3", {"demand": 25}),
    ("N4"{"demand": 18})])
```

I want my Pyomo Abstract model to create constraints and decision variables dynamically. Like,

```
def mymodel():
    model = AbstractModel()
    g=mygraph() #mygraph passed to abstract model
    model.nodes_range = RangeSet(1,len(g))# this creates a parameter with same size of the graph
    model.C = Param(model.nodes_range, within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers) #one parameter for each node

    def constraint_rule(model, i): #dummy constraint
         return sum(model.decision_var*demand_node1)<=something
    model.const1=Constraint(model.nodes_range, rule=constraint_rule)
    
    model.obj1 = Objective(my objective) #my dummy objective
    
    status = SolverFactory('glpk')
    results = status.solve(model)
    assert_optimal_termination(results)
    model.display()
mymodel()
```

But the **model.const1.pprint()** command is giving 0 constraints. Can you guide me with the logic?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `model.create_instance` call to actually construct the abstract model into a concrete instance. Calling `pprint` on abstract model components will always return empty components because they haven't been constructed.

I don't see anything in your example model that would require an `AbstractModel` so you could also try using a `ConcreteModel` instead and then you could call `pprint` on components any time after declaration.